# Upload image to an album and collect likes from users

Tags: c#, facebook

I need to build a simple C# application that will upload images into a Facebook album and collect the number of likes and by which users.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5 with Facebook 6.0.20

Any help is really appreciated and if someone can also give me a link for a tutorial but I need one that is not old as I have noticed some classes seem not to be working in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Facebook Graph API. You can download it from [Facebook's developer](https://developers.facebook.com) page.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) is a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you Jay for the link pretty helpful.